# validating number of characters allowed in django python

Tags: python, django

I want to validate my forms. This is my code.

```
 class SMSTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        template_format = self.cleaned_data.get('template_form')

        if len(template_format) > 160:
            raise forms.ValidationError('SMS content too long.')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Is that `clean` method inside the inner Meta class.

Comment: sorry, just fixed that

Answer (score 1):

Unindent your `clean` method and define it in `SMSTemplateForm` class instead.

It seems to me that you have written the `clean` method inside class `Meta` instead of in `SMSTemplateForm` class. That's most likely the reason your `clean` method is not working.

Comment: still not working.. it still accepting more 160 char .

Comment: Please fix your indentation in the question first. The code inside `clean` method should be indented.

Comment: What are the fields defined in your model.

Comment: name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="The name of the Template.")
    template_format = models.TextField(max_length=255, help_text= 220) .   those one are my fields

Comment: Your code seems fine. Most likely the `view` that's using the form is not calling `form.is_valid` method.

Comment: and how could i fix this ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150628/discussion-between-patcho-and-hspandher).